# Delete and redirect lines in Vim to another file

Tags: vim, scripting, vi

I want to delete say last 10 lines and move it to another file.

What I currently do is:

- select last 10 lines in visual mode,
- write these lines by `:'<,'>w` to other file,
- and then delete selected lines.

Is there any more efficient way I can do this?

Comment: efficient meaning faster? or less step?

Answer (score 6):

You can remove one step by doing this:

- visually select the lines
- `:!> newfile.txt`

This will use an external command to write the lines to the given filename, and simultaneously delete them because nothing was output from the command.

If you want to append to a file instead of overwriting it, then use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: This is a great trick and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ex` commands instead. e.g.

`:1,10w file.name`   *Write the **first** ten lines*

`:$-9,$w file.name` *Write the **last** ten lines (the dollar sign denotes last line)*

---

With the code below in your `.vimrc` you can use the command `:MoveTo file.name`

```
function! MoveLastLines(f)
  exe '$-9,$w ' . a:f    "write last ten lines to the passed filename
  $-9,$d                 "delete last ten lines
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -range MoveTo :call MoveLastLines(<f-args>)
```

---

In normal mode the steps you mentioned (`GV9k:w file.name gvd`) are the most efficient in my opinion.

Comment: Your command incorrectly handles ranges, since it always operates on the last ten lines.  And by the way, if the `:write` command fails for some reason, user is not notified about that.

Comment: @ib The range is correct re-read the question or the mapping in your answer.  The write notification will now be visible since I removed the `silent!`

Comment: The range referring to the last ten lines is correct (it was backwards, though).  What I said is that the command `MoveTo` as you define it here does not handle ranges correctly.  By your definition it accepts line number ranges, but completely ignores them operating always on the last ten lines.  Either it should not accept a range, or should take it into account.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "you can use Ex commands *instead*"?  As it is clear from the question, @shampa uses the `:write` command on Visual area range `'<,'>`, so @shampa already uses an Ex command.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way of writing a range of lines to file and deleting them
afterwards is to run the command

```
:$-9,$w path | '[,']d
```

However, it is inconvenient for frequent use if the file name is not constant.

Below is the function `MoveToFile()` implementing the command with the same
name.  The whole thing wraps the following two steps: write a range of lines
using `:write` command (see `:help :w_f`, `:help :w!`, `:help :w_a`), then
delete that range.<sup>1</sup>

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang -bar MoveToFile
\   :<line1>,<line2>call MoveToFile(<q-args>, <bang>0)
function! MoveToFile(fname, overwrite) range
    let r = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline
    exe r 'w' . ' !'[a:overwrite] . fnameescape(a:fname)
    exe r 'd'
endfunction
```

Now you can use the above command to cover all frequent use cases.  For
example, to move visually selected range of lines to file use the mapping

```
:vnoremap <leader>m :MoveToFile
```

This mapping triggers semi-complete command calling `:MoveToFile` for the
range of lines selected in Visual mode (`'<,'>`).  You need only to type
a file name and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you frequently do this for the last ten lines of a buffer, create a similar
mapping just for this case:

```
:nnoremap <leader>m :$-9,$MoveToFile
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  Specified lines are deleted into the default register
overwriting its previous contents.  To delete lines without affecting
registers change the last command in `MoveToFile()` to

```
exe r 'd_'
```

In this case `:delete` uses the black hole register (see `:help :d` and `:help
"_`) instead of the default one.

Answer (score 1):

While you use visual mode for selecting lines, you can delete just written down lines pressing only three keys: `d'>` (see `:help '>`).

Comment: Only if the cursor is positioned exactly at the first character of the first of those last ten lines.