# Vim E139: Workaround

Tags: vim, vi

I have a `MoveToFile` Function that appends selected text to a file and then deletes it.

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang -bar MoveToFile
\   :<line1>,<line2>call MoveToFile(<q-args>, <bang>0)
function! MoveToFile(fname, overwrite) range
    let r = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline
    exe r 'w>>' . ' !'[a:overwrite] . fnameescape(a:fname)
    exe r 'd'
endfunction
```

A problem arises when the file I'm trying to append to is already open in Vim. How can I get around this?

Comment: See also the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7723380/254635) (to the question "[Delete and redirect lines in Vim to another file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7720520/254635)") this function has been copied from.

Comment: You have introduced a mistake when modified `MoveToFile()` to append to a file instead of overwriting it.  The second line of the function should read `exe r 'w' . ' !'[a:overwrite] . '>>' . fnameescape(a:fname)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `E139: File is loaded in another buffer`. If you really need
to handle this corner case, yank the contents, open the existing buffer via `:buffer {fname}`, and paste them:

```
try
   exe r 'w>>' . ' !'[a:overwrite] . fnameescape(a:fname)
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E139/
    exe r 'yank'
    exe 'sbuffer' fnameescape(a:fname)
    $put
    hide
endtry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `writefile()` (note that this will overwrite file hence must first get current contents hence is unusable for large ones):

```
function MoveToFile(fname, _) range abort
    let lines=readfile(a:fname, 'b')
    if !empty(lines) && empty(lines[-1])
        call remove(lines, -1)
    endif
    let [first, last]=((a:firstline>a:lastline)?([a:lastline, a:firstline]):([a:firstline, a:lastline]))
    let lines+=getline(first, last)+['']
    call writefile(lines, a:fname, 'b')
    execute first.','.last.'delete _'
endfunction
```

Note: to get the same encoding as with `:w>>` you need to replace line

```
    let lines+=getline(first, last)+['']
```

with

```
    let lines+=map(getline(first, last), 'iconv(v:val, &enc, &fenc)')+['']
```

. To also respect `'dos'` file format:

```
    let lines+=map(getline(first, last), 'iconv(v:val, &enc, &fenc)'.((&ff is# 'dos')?('."\r"'):('')))+[(&ff is# 'dos')?("\r"):('')]
```

(respecting `'mac'` file format is trickier).

Comment: When you're dealing with multiple encodings, you'd also have to take care of the necessary conversions; `writefile()` doesn't do that for you; `:w` does.

Comment: @IngoKarkat False. When appending write does not care about target file encoding, but cares about `&fenc`. Thus when using original solution and appending from files with multiple encodings you will get file with a mix of encodings. When using my solution you will get file encoded in `&enc`. `getline()` will output already recoded lines thus no need to care about source file encoding. Of course, you will need to run `iconv()` if you need something other then `&enc` though.

Comment: I'm assuming the append is just a special case, a convenience when the command is invoked multiple times from the same buffer. Otherwise, there could be a mix of encodings, as you've pointed out. Nonetheless, I think picking up `&fenc` is more in line with the default behavior than using `&enc`, but there's no definite right or wrong.